# Printing out current date

Tags: c, date, calendar

Implement a function that determines and prints out the current year, month and day. For example:

`Today is 03/04/2014.`

Code so far that I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{

    int days, weeks, months, years, option, rmd, currentyear, currentmonth;
    int daysinjan, daysinfeb, daysinmarch;
    time_t seconds;
    seconds = time(NULL);

    days = seconds/(60*60*24);
    weeks = seconds/((60*60*24)*7);
    rmd=seconds%31557600;
    months = ((seconds/31557600) * 12)+(((float)rmd/31557600)*12);
    years = days/(365.25);

    currentyear = 1970 + years;
    currentmonth = (((float)rmd/31557600)*12)+1;

    printf("%ld/%ld", currentmonth,currentyear);

    return 0;
}
```

Please do not mind all the useless stuff in the code, this question is part of a project and i simply used the code from my previous question to try and work with that code in order to solve this question. The problem i have is that i cannot print the current day of the month that it is, because of this i feel that i have gone about this question wrongly.

Answer (score 3):

This uses standard library calls to do all the math for you.
***[From Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Functions-Example.html)***:

```
     #include <time.h>
     #include <stdio.h>

     #define SIZE 256

     int main (void)
     {
       char buffer[SIZE];
       time_t curtime;
       struct tm *loctime;

       /* Get the current time. */
       curtime = time (NULL);

       /* Convert it to local time representation. */
       loctime = localtime (&curtime);

       /* Print out the date and time in the standard format. */
       fputs (asctime (loctime), stdout);

       /* Print it out in a nice format. */
       strftime (buffer, SIZE, "Today is %A, %B %d.\n", loctime);
       fputs (buffer, stdout);
       strftime (buffer, SIZE, "The time is %I:%M %p.\n", loctime);
       fputs (buffer, stdout);

       return 0;
     }
```

***If you wanted to*** create this as a function to return a string, you could do it like this:

```
char * getTimeString (char *str)
{
    //replace this comment with relevant code from above with (at least) two additional lines:
    strcpy(str, buffer);
    return str;
}
```

***Call it*** like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *timeStr;
    timeStr = malloc(30);//sufficient length to accept values assigned in getTimeString()
    printf("%s\n", getTimeString(timeStr);
    free(timeStr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly agree that the _right_ way to go about this question is to use the existing date/time utility functions.  Unless as an academic exercise, there's little point to trying to manually convert from unixtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h> // for time_t
#include <stdio.h> // for printf

int main () {

int days, weeks, months, years, option, rmd, currentyear, currentmonth;

int daysinjan, daysinfeb, daysinmarch;

time_t seconds;

seconds = time(NULL);

    days = seconds/(60*60*24);
    weeks = seconds/((60*60*24)*7);
    rmd=seconds%31557600;
    months = ((seconds/31557600) * 12)+(((float)rmd/31557600)*12);
    years = days/(365.25);

    currentyear = 1970 + years;
    currentmonth = (((float)rmd/31557600)*12)+1;


    printf("%ld/%ld", currentmonth,currentyear);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide a bit more information about your code - what you changed and why your changes make it work - in order to make your answer a bit more complete.

Comment: Is that code anything more than a copy/paste of the question's code ?